# Creating an Array with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays

I have looked at several posts on stackoveflow for creating an array and haven't found what I was looking for yet...so many different answers I would like to attempt and get one clear that is closest to what I am trying to accomplish.

Say I want to create an array using this query:

"select * from products"

How is this accomplished most efficiently?

Thank you.

PS - note that I am starting from scratch.

**UPDATE**

My config file:

```
`[root@CentOS testphp]# vi config.php
<?php
// Connection's Parameters
$db_host="localhost";
$db_name="tablename";
$username="username";
$password="password";
$db_con=mysql_connect($db_host,$username,$password);
$connection_string=mysql_select_db($db_name);
// Connection
mysql_connect($db_host,$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($db_name);
?>`
```

The php code I am trying to create the array with...I am getting a Syntax Error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /var/www/html/testphp/test.php on line 2

I get the same error:

```
`[root@CentOS testphp]# vi test.php
<?php include('config.php')
$query = "select * from upload_products";
$dataArray = array();
$result = mysqli_query($query, $link);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
$dataArray[] = $row;
}
var_dump($dataArray); //Now you have your array.
?>`
```

Any ideas...It feels like I am missing something here. And, yes I have read the documentation...used their code line by line, reviewed the code and still get the same error as I do with all the code examples I have found on the web.

Comment: you should read php manual: http://php.net/manual/en/index.php, search about sql querying

Comment: If you are confused by the many different answers, asking yet another broad question won't help. What specific problem do you have with any of the existing solutions?

Comment: Homework question? You seem to need to start with PHP before you delve into MySQL. Read The Manual.

Comment: What is it that you have trying to accomplish? Post your code if you have tried something. Too broad a question... MySQLi/PDO has several functions for the same...http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php they each come with sample code....

Answer (score 2):

There is not definite way to convert a database result object into an associative array directory. You will have to create this array your result.

```
$query = "...";
$dataArray = array();
$result = mysqli_query($query, $link);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $dataArray[] = $row;
}
var_dump($dataArray); //Now you have your array.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM products");
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
```

but you will receive only one row in $result variable. If you want to fetch all you have to apply any loop on it: e.g.:

```
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM products");
while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
 //do something with your results 
 //you can access result like: $result['column_name']
}
```

Is it clear for you now?

Comment: Please stop advertising the deprecated `mysql_` functions.

Comment: Assuming OP even has a database, how do they connect to it?

Comment: @deceze: Was just gonna post the same! :)

Comment: @emte - I am getting this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /var/www/html/jmdb1/test4.php on line 5  <<line 5 is the line with the query in it. Any ideas?

Comment: sorry changed from mysql to mysqli. Of course it's better to user OOP...

Comment: @user1114330 can you post beginning of your file? few first lines?

Comment: hold on, I'm trying to read test4.php contents through my crystal ball *hope you understand*

Comment: @LeleDumbo I am using the example 1 here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php  and getting this Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /var/www/html/jmdb1/test6.php on line 20  ...any ideas?

Comment: the code is OK, tested. that means something wrong with your code. if it's exactly the same as you said, then the problem is how you execute it (included from other file, etc.). anyway, line 20 in the link is empty line, so yours must be different.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) or [mysql_fetch_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) to get the mysql query response as an array. Following are the code example of how to use both.

With  **mysql_fetch_assoc** :

```
$query = "select * from products";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (mysql_num_rows($result) != 0) {
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          //every row will represent a record as an array
          // your code   
   }
}
```

With  **mysql_fetch_array** :

```
 $query = "select * from products";
 $result = mysql_query($query);
 if (mysql_num_rows($result) != 0) {
       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
           //every row will represent a record as an array
           //  your code
      }
 }
```

If you have any doubt further, please refer php manual.

Comment: I tried example one on this page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php  and am getting this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /var/www/html/jmdb1/test6.php on line 20   ....any thoughts?

Comment: see, It is syntax error. PHP is not able to parse your syntax.. so go through your code deeply. BTW what code is written on line no. 20

Comment: I guess where I am confused is that I am using a link that was provided by someone answering the question.  That link happens to be on the php.net site and its not MY code per se.  I can review it, but why would there be a syntax error in the first place? exit; is the only thing on line 20.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php  Example #1

Comment: Please check, whether your mysql extension is loaded or not in PHP.ini. If it is loaded, then check the mysql connection in your code. This is the only way to debug the your testcode, as even i am not able to figure why your code is throwing the error, until i can review your code..

Comment: I guess I am confused because "my code" is exactly what is shown in example #1 in the link provided: php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php   ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@ $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'dbname');

  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
     echo 'Error: Could not connect to database.  Please try again later.';
     exit;
  }

  $query = "select * from books";
  $result = $db->query($query);

  $num_results = $result->num_rows;

  echo "<p>Number of books found: ".$num_results."</p>";

  for ($i=0; $i <$num_results; $i++) {
     $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    // echo something here
  }

  $result->free();
  $db->close();
```